# NSIS : Why "Text" from text box value became numeric?

Tags: textbox, nsis, modern-ui

I've created a custom page`(.nsh)` and there are 3 text boxes `(url, user, password)` for user typing in it and `.NSI` file will get these data to write into a properties file.

But those text became to numeric such `9502966, 4718976 and 8455398.`
What should I do?

This is my example code:

## AcustomPage.nsh

...

```
!macro create_AcustomPage APP_NAME CUS_URL CUS_USER CUS_PWD
Page custom create_AcustomPage
Function create_AcustomPage
   ...
   ${NSD_CreateText} 60u 50u 60% 11u "${CUS_URL}"
   Pop $AcustomPage.url
   ${NSD_CreateText} 60u 50u 60% 11u "${CUS_USER}"
   Pop $AcustomPage.user
   ${NSD_CreateText} 60u 50u 60% 11u "${CUS_PWD}"
   Pop $AcustomPage.pwd
   ...
FunctionEnd
...
!macroend
```

## Project.nsi

...

```
 !insertmacro create_AcustomPage "${NAME} ${VERSION}-${RELEASE}" "url.localhost" "username" "password"
...    
${ConfigWriteS} "$INSTDIR\configure.properties" "custom_url=" "$CUS_URL" $R0
${ConfigWriteS} "$INSTDIR\configure.properties" "custom_user=" "$CUS_USER" $R0
${ConfigWriteS} "$INSTDIR\configure.properties" "custom_password=" "$CUS_PWD" $R0
```

Result #configure.properties

```
addi_url=18940788
addi_user=6750598
addi_password=11469950
```

But it should be:

```
addi_url=usl.localhost
addi_user=username
addi_password=password
```

Thanks,

Comment: How are you reading those fields? You should paste some code in order to get help..

Comment: @FranciscoR Thank you very much, now I added my codes here. Thanks.

Comment: In the future you should post code that actually compiles, you are still hiding a lot of important stuff so we have to guess what the problem is...

Comment: My apologized and thank you @Anders, Next time I'll rectify itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you are writing the controls handle to the file but it is impossible to know because of your poor example code.

It should probably look something like this:

```
InstallDir "$Temp\Test"

!include TextFunc.nsh
!include nsDialogs.nsh


var hCtlUrl
var hCtlUsr
var hCtlPwd

!define DefaultUrl "url.localhost"
!define DefaultUsr "foo"
!define DefaultPwd "bar"

Function mypageCreate
nsDialogs::Create 1018
Pop $0
${NSD_CreateText} 60u 30u 60% 11u "${DefaultUrl}"
Pop $hCtlUrl
${NSD_CreateText} 60u 50u 60% 11u "${DefaultUsr}"
Pop $hCtlUsr
${NSD_CreateText} 60u 70u 60% 11u "${DefaultPwd}"
Pop $hCtlPwd
nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd

Function mypageLeave
${NSD_GetText} $hCtlUrl $0
${ConfigWriteS} "$INSTDIR\configure.properties" "custom_url=" "$0" $R0
${NSD_GetText} $hCtlUsr $0
${ConfigWriteS} "$INSTDIR\configure.properties" "custom_user=" "$0" $R0
${NSD_GetText} $hCtlPwd $0
${ConfigWriteS} "$INSTDIR\configure.properties" "custom_password=" "$0" $R0
FunctionEnd

Page Directory
Page InstFiles
Page Custom mypageCreate mypageLeave
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need variables to store control's HWND. You also need a "leave" function for your custom page. It'll be executed when user clicks on Next button. That function has to read the text controls. Something like this:

```
Var customer_url
Var customer_user
Var customer_password

Page custom create_AcustomPage leave_AcustomPage

Function create_AcustomPage
   ...
   ${NSD_CreateText} 60u 50u 60% 11u "Type your url..."
   Pop $0
   ${NSD_CreateText} 60u 50u 60% 11u "Type your username..."
   Pop $1
   ${NSD_CreateText} 60u 50u 60% 11u "Type your password..."
   Pop $2
   ...
FunctionEnd

Function leave_AcustomPage
  # Read form
  ${NSD_GetText} $0 $customer_url
  ${NSD_GetText} $1 $customer_user
  ${NSD_GetText} $2 $customer_password

  # save form to config file
  ${ConfigWriteS} "$INSTDIR\configure.properties" "custom_url=" "$customer_url" $R0
  ${ConfigWriteS} "$INSTDIR\configure.properties" "custom_user=" "$customer_user" $R0
  ${ConfigWriteS} "$INSTDIR\configure.properties" "custom_password=" "$customer_password" $R0
FunctionEnd
```